# HttpURLConnection setting POST parameter URL

Tags: java, http, soap, httpurlconnection

I am trying to access a SOAP service. To do this I am creating the SOAP request manually (which I preefer). The problem is that when I do

```
URL urli = new URL("http://www.myserver.com//x/y/z/a/b/c/d/myUrlWS.jws");
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) urli.openConnection();
c.setRequestMethod("POST");
c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
c.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", bytes.length+"");
c.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "");
...
c.getInputStream();
```

The thing is that the http header shows this way:

```
POST /x/y/z/a/b/c/d/myUrlWS.jws
...(reset of http header)...

SOAP Message
```

I am getting an error form the server and I think that the POST in the http should be like:

```
POST /
```

or

```
POST /action
```

or

```
POST /myUrlWS.jws
```

So I dont know how to change the POST parameter in the header. How do I do that without changing the connection URL/address?

EDIT - The SOAP Reply from server

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Header/><env:Body><env:Fault><faultcode>env:Server</faultcode><faultstring>[Server CodecHandler] Failed to decode 
 -&gt; Unable to find xml element for parameter: documentos
</faultstring><detail><java:string xmlns:java="java.io">weblogic.wsee.codec.CodecException: Unable to find xml element for parameter: documentos
</java:string></detail></env:Fault></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

FULL HTTP REQUEST

```
    POST /x/y/z/a/b/c/d/myUrlWS.jws HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    SOAPAction: 
    User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_75
    Host: wwwW.somehost.some.gov.br
    Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 2026

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:WL5G3N0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:WL5G3N1="http://www.openuri.org/" xmlns:WL5G3N2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:WL5G3N3="http://www.openuri.org/2006/12/wsdl/upgradedJWS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <WL5G3N1:enviarDados xmlns:WL5G3N1="http://www.openuri.org/">
                <emitente>
                    <CNPJEmitente>11111111</CNPJEmitente>
                    <Email>my@email.com</Email>
                </emitente>
                <documentos>
                    <Documento>
                        <TipoPagamento>1</TipoPagamento>
                        <TipoDocumento>2</TipoDocumento>
                        <DataPagamento>13/04/15</DataPagamento>
                        <ItensPagamentos>
                            <ItemPagamento>
                                <TipoId>1</TipoId>
                                <Cnpj>1111111111</Cnpj>
                                <CodigoProduto>11111</CodigoProduto>
                                <DataFatoGerador>13/04/15</DataFatoGerador>
                                <DataVencimento>13/04/15</DataVencimento>
                                <DddContribuinte>16</DddContribuinte>
                                <EnderecoContribuinte>SOME NAME</EnderecoContribuinte>
                                <MunicipioContribuinte>NAME</MunicipioContribuinte>
                                <UFContribuinte>SP</UFContribuinte>
                                <CepContribuinte>11111111</CepContribuinte>
                                <TelefoneContribuinte>111111</TelefoneContribuinte>
                                <Natureza>1</Natureza>
                                <NomeRazaoSocial>SOME NAME</NomeRazaoSocial>
                                <NotaFiscalCnpj>1111111</NotaFiscalCnpj>
                                <NotaFiscalDataEmissao>2014-12-04</NotaFiscalDataEmissao>
                                <NotaFiscalNumero>111111</NotaFiscalNumero>
                                <NotaFiscalSerie>1</NotaFiscalSerie>
                                <NotaFiscalTipo>NF-e</NotaFiscalTipo>
                                <NumControleContribuinte>111111</NumControleContribuinte>
                                <TipoApuracao>2</TipoApuracao>
                                <PeriodoReferenciaAno>2015</PeriodoReferenciaAno>
                                <PeriodoReferenciaMes>04</PeriodoReferenciaMes>
                                <PeriodoReferenciaDecendio>2</PeriodoReferenciaDecendio>
                                <DiaVencimento>13/04/15</DiaVencimento>
                                <ValorICMSPrincipal>221.21</ValorICMSPrincipal>
                                <ValorTotal>221.21</ValorTotal>
                            </ItemPagamento>
                        </ItensPagamentos>
                    </Documento>
                </documentos>
            </WL5G3N1:enviarDados>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

WSDL here:
[WSDL](http://www1.fazenda.rj.gov.br/projetoGCTBradesco/br/gov/rj/sef/gct/webservice/GerarDocumentoArrecadacaoWS.jws?WSDL)

Comment: Is there any stack-trace? or what is the exact error?

Comment: I cant access the server but I get a HTTP 500 with the SOAP reply added above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the exeption that you Got, I can guess that your SOAP payload message is malformed.

The each tag of XML message should be mentioned by a namespace. In your case you are mentioning the namespace as **"WL5G3N1"** in the following tag.

`<WL5G3N1:enviarDados xmlns:WL5G3N1="http://www.openuri.org/">`

So You should use WL5G3N1 throughout the message for refering each and every XML element.

So the following XML should work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:WL5G3N0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:WL5G3N1="http://www.openuri.org/"
    xmlns:WL5G3N2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:WL5G3N3="http://www.openuri.org/2006/12/wsdl/upgradedJWS"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <WL5G3N1:enviarDados xmlns:WL5G3N1="http://www.openuri.org/">
            <WL5G3N1:emitente>
                <WL5G3N1:CNPJEmitente>11111111</WL5G3N1:CNPJEmitente>
                <WL5G3N1:Email>my@email.com</WL5G3N1:Email>
            </WL5G3N1:emitente>
            <WL5G3N1:documentos>
                <WL5G3N1:Documento>
                    <WL5G3N1:TipoPagamento>1</WL5G3N1:TipoPagamento>
                    <WL5G3N1:TipoDocumento>2</WL5G3N1:TipoDocumento>
                    <WL5G3N1:DataPagamento>13/04/15</WL5G3N1:DataPagamento>
                    <WL5G3N1:ItensPagamentos>
                        <WL5G3N1:ItemPagamento>
                            <WL5G3N1:TipoId>1</WL5G3N1:TipoId>
                            <WL5G3N1:Cnpj>1111111111</WL5G3N1:Cnpj>
                            <WL5G3N1:CodigoProduto>11111</WL5G3N1:CodigoProduto>
                            <WL5G3N1:DataFatoGerador>13/04/15</WL5G3N1:DataFatoGerador>
                            <WL5G3N1:DataVencimento>13/04/15</WL5G3N1:DataVencimento>
                            <WL5G3N1:DddContribuinte>16</WL5G3N1:DddContribuinte>
                            <WL5G3N1:EnderecoContribuinte>SOME NAME</WL5G3N1:EnderecoContribuinte>
                            <WL5G3N1:MunicipioContribuinte>NAME</WL5G3N1:MunicipioContribuinte>
                            <WL5G3N1:UFContribuinte>SP</WL5G3N1:UFContribuinte>
                            <WL5G3N1:CepContribuinte>11111111</WL5G3N1:CepContribuinte>
                            <WL5G3N1:TelefoneContribuinte>111111
                            </WL5G3N1:TelefoneContribuinte>
                            <WL5G3N1:Natureza>1</WL5G3N1:Natureza>
                            <WL5G3N1:NomeRazaoSocial>SOME NAME</WL5G3N1:NomeRazaoSocial>
                            <WL5G3N1:NotaFiscalCnpj>1111111</WL5G3N1:NotaFiscalCnpj>
                            <WL5G3N1:NotaFiscalDataEmissao>2014-12-04</WL5G3N1:NotaFiscalDataEmissao>
                            <WL5G3N1:NotaFiscalNumero>111111</WL5G3N1:NotaFiscalNumero>
                            <WL5G3N1:NotaFiscalSerie>1</WL5G3N1:NotaFiscalSerie>
                            <WL5G3N1:NotaFiscalTipo>NF-e</WL5G3N1:NotaFiscalTipo>
                            <WL5G3N1:NumControleContribuinte>111111
                            </WL5G3N1:NumControleContribuinte>
                            <WL5G3N1:TipoApuracao>2</WL5G3N1:TipoApuracao>
                            <WL5G3N1:PeriodoReferenciaAno>2015</WL5G3N1:PeriodoReferenciaAno>
                            <WL5G3N1:PeriodoReferenciaMes>04</WL5G3N1:PeriodoReferenciaMes>
                            <WL5G3N1:PeriodoReferenciaDecendio>2
                            </WL5G3N1:PeriodoReferenciaDecendio>
                            <WL5G3N1:DiaVencimento>13/04/15</WL5G3N1:DiaVencimento>
                            <WL5G3N1:ValorICMSPrincipal>221.21</WL5G3N1:ValorICMSPrincipal>
                            <WL5G3N1:ValorTotal>221.21</WL5G3N1:ValorTotal>
                        </WL5G3N1:ItemPagamento>
                    </WL5G3N1:ItensPagamentos>
                </WL5G3N1:Documento>
            </WL5G3N1:documentos>
        </WL5G3N1:enviarDados>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Then you may have to give us the complete Soap request and the code which handles the message.

Comment: I have got the issue. Please refer to my updated answer.

Comment: The XML that I have mentioned may have other issues. But still answers your question.